# Run remote Python script via curl

Tags: python, bash, curl, wget

I have a Python file  where I can just run like this locally

```
script.py --ip=172.19.242.32 --mac=102030405060
```

Now I upload the script to my VM IP: `45.55.88.55`.

How can I call the script via cURL and pass in proper flags?

I've tried

```
curl 45.55.88.55/script.py  | python --ip=172.19.242.32 --mac=102030405060
```

and

```
curl 45.55.88.55/script.py --ip=172.19.242.32 --mac=102030405060  | python
```

Both are not working. How can I debug this further?

Comment: try using `ssh` to execute a script in the remote server.

Comment: Is there a way to prevent ssh ? I can share script with my team but not access into my VM. I’m trying to create a separation

Comment: Are you trying to store the script on the server, but run it locally? Or do you want to run the script on the server as well?

Comment: I want to store the script a Remote VM so I can run from other VMs or even locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arguments come after the script name. To use standard input as the script, use `-` as the name:

```
curl 45.55.88.55/script.py  | python - --ip=172.19.242.32 --mac=102030405060
```

This is a pretty standard Unix argument convention, although not all programs obey it (mostly older programs).

Answer (score 1):

As @Barmar rightly said, Instead of running

```
curl 45.55.88.55/script.py  | python --ip=172.19.242.32 --mac=102030405060
```

which will make you miss your argument that is most times needed after whatever script name you're running. Which implies that you will need the short`-` delimiter character as the name